# multiple ajax async not in order and need synchronous behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

Sorry, My first language is not English. I am not sure that if I explain my question properly.

My code is like a main function have two ajax functions (Use ajax function to get foursquare API)

```
main(){

      ajax1();

      ajax2();

   all other codes
}
```

the ajax2() function has to get result from ajax1() as input and then return result(actually result was pushed in to global array).

all other codes should be processed after two ajax functions are finished. I tried the asyn: false  but it is not working. My html file include newest jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
```

I try the jquery function $.when().done() function and the first ajax works. However, the second ajax() function was in the for loop. The for loop will destroy the mechanism of $.when().done() function:

first ajax: in firstjson function
Second ajax: in transfer function

```
 function firstjson(tmpName,tmpLoc,PhotoJson,foursq){
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: foursq,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(json) {

              for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var resultname = json['response']['venues'][i].name;
                var resultlocation = json['response']['venues'][i].location;
                var resultlat = resultlocation.lat;
                var resultlng = resultlocation.lng;
                var tmpmarker = new google.maps.LatLng(resultlat,resultlng)

                tmpName.push(resultname);
                tmpLoc.push(tmpmarker);
                var resultid = json['response']['venues'][i].id;
                var tmpPhotoJason = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+ resultid +'/photos?';
                PhotoJson.push(tmpPhotoJason);


              }


        }
   });
 }


    function transfer(PhotoJson,PhotoURL){
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

           return $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: PhotoJson[i],
            dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(json) {
                  resultphoto = json['response']['photos']['items'];
                  photoprefix = resultphoto[i].prefix;
                  photopresuffix = resultphoto[i].suffix;
                  photourl = photoprefix+"150x150" + photopresuffix;
                  PhotoURL.push(photourl);
              }

        });
      }
    }

    $.when(firstjson(tmpName,tmpLoc,PhotoJson,foursq)).done(function(){
            alert("test1");
          $.when(transfer(PhotoJson,PhotoURL).done(function(){
               console.log(PhotoURL);
              all other codes!!!!
         });
    });
```

//PhotoURL is global array

So the first "when" function work properly. alert("test1") work after the firstjson was done. However the for loop inside transfer function will break the when function. How can I fix the problem. Please help me. I will appreciate you can give me any related information. Thanks!!!

Comment: loop `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { return ...; }` in `transfer` will execute only once

Comment: You just have to call ajax2() in the callback (success) of ajax1().

Comment: Thx, could you please help me any way that I can process all other codes after push all photourl in to PhotoURL array.

Comment: I try to call ajax2() in the callback (success) of ajax1(). However, the program will run all other codes before run callback (success) of ajax2().

Answer (score 0):

This will execute ajax2 after ajax1

```
function anotherMethod(){
   //Here you do all that you want to do after the last $ajax call
}
main(){
        firstjson(tmpName,tmpLoc,PhotoJson,foursq)
        .then(transfer(PhotoJson,PhotoURL))
        .then(anotherMethod);
}
```

As you are returning a promise from the first with the "return $ajax..."

So you organice your code like this:

in methods with ajax calls you return the call as you are doing now

```
return $.ajax();
```

that returns a promise that you chain.
And you put what you want to do in another method so you call it in the last "then".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried this before and had a problem. This can execute ajax2 after ajax1 properly but how can I run other codes after ajax2 (transfer) was finished?

Comment: $.when(firstjson(tmpName,tmpLoc,PhotoJson,PhotoURL,foursq)) .then(function (){transfer(PhotoJson,PhotoURL)})                      .then(function (){alert("test3")});

Comment: and I add alert("test1") in call back (success) of firstjson and alert("test2") in call back (success) of transfer. The test3 will show before test2. So all other codes still run before ajax2 (transfer).

Answer (score 0):

## Non-Blocking Example

You should use non-blocking code. You can turn async off (`async: false`) but this can easily be done in a non-blocking manor using callback functions.

```
function main(){
  $.ajax({ // First ajax call (ajax1)
    url: "first/ajax/url",
    type: "GET", // POST or GET
    data: {}, // POST or GET data being passed to first URL
    success: function(x){ // Callback when request is successfully returned
      // x is your returned data
      $.ajax({ // Second ajax call (ajax2)
        url: "second/ajax/url",
        type: "GET", // POST or GET
        data: {
          thatThing: x
        }, // POST or GET data passed to second URL
        success: function(y){
          // y is your second returned data
          // all other codes that use y should be here
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

This would be the non-blocking approach, nest your function within "success" callback functions. Nest ajax2 within ajax1's "success" callback to ensure that ajax2 is not executed before ajax1 has returned and nest your "all other codes" inside the "success" callback of ajax2 to ensure they are not executed until ajax2 has returned.

---

## Blocking Example

If you absolutely must (please avoid at all cost) you can disable async which will block all JavaScript code from executing until the ajax has returned. This may cause your browser to temporarily freeze until the ajax request has returned (depending on the browser).

```
function main(){
  var x = ajax1();
  var y = ajax2(x);
  window["y"] = y; // push to global as you requested but why?
  // All other codes that can now use y
}
function ajax1(){
  var x;
  $.ajax({
    url: "first/ajax/url",
    async: false,
    type: "GET", // POST or GET,
    data: {}, // POST or GET data being passed to first URL
    success: function(r){x=r}
  });
  return x;
}
function ajax2(x){
  var y;
  $.ajax({
    url: "second/ajax/url",
    async: false,
    type: "GET", // POST or GET,
    data: {
      thatThing: x
    }, // POST or GET data being passed to second URL
    success: function(r){y=r}
  });
  return y;
}
```

Once again I stress, try not to disable async that will cause your code to block and is BAD code. If you absolutely 100% have to for some reason than than it can be done but you should attempt to learn how to write non-blocking code using callbacks as the first example does.

---

## Social Network Example

Now I'll do an example of an ajax call to get an array of your friends IDs, and then a series of ajax calls to get each of your friends profiles. The first ajax will get the list, the second will get their profiles and store then, and then when all profiles have been retrieved some other code can be ran.

For this example, the url `https://api.site.com/{userID}/friends/` retrieves an Object with a list of friends IDs for a particular user, and `https://api.site.com/{userID}/profile/` gets any users profile.
Obviously this is a simplified api as you will probably need to first establish a connection with a apikey and get a token for this connection and the token would likely need to be passed to the api uris but I think it should still illustrate the point.

```
function getFriends(userID, callback){
   $.ajax({
     url: "https://api.site.com/"+userID+"/friends/",
     success: function(x){
       var counter = 0;
       var profiles = [];
       for(var i=0;i<x.friendIDs.length;i++){
         $.ajax({
           url: "https://api.site.com/"+x.friendIDs[i]+"/profile/",
           success: function(profile){
             profiles.push(profile);
             counter++;
             if(counter == x.friendIDs.length) callback(profiles);
           }
         });
       }
     }
   });
}
getFreinds("dustinpoissant", function(friends){
  // Do stuff with the 'friends' array here
})
```

This example is "Non-blocking", if this example were done in a "blocking" way then we would ask for 1 friends profile, then wait for its response, then request the next and wait and so on. If we had hundreds of friends you can see how this would take a very long time for all ajax calls to complete. In this example, which is non-blocking, all requests for profiles are made at the same time (within 1ms) and then can all be returned at almost exactly the same time and a counter is used to see if we have gotten responses from all the requests. This is way way way faster than using the blocking method especially if you have lots of friends.

Comment: Hi, I try your solution by using callback functions and it works. However, my second ajax function (transfer) is in a for loop. I need process "all other codes" after the loop finish so that I can get all photourl. Could you please tell me how to solve the problem ?

Comment: The url of second ajax need to be changed each time by PhotoJson[i] so it need to be inside a for loop

Comment: Well then you need to set up a return counter.  Each time the second ajax returns the counter goes up and is compared to the length of your array. When the count is equal to the length call your "other code"

Comment: See my update for an example of a ajax call in a loop and executing a callback after all ajax calls have been completed